# Failed to retrieve all data for some end date or today

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Show error when trying to retrieve data between date range, the error shows when 21 August and above but no error until 20 August only.

```
    $sql2 = "SELECT trans_details.*, company.comp_name FROM trans_details INNER JOIN company ON trans_details.comp_id=company.comp_id WHERE trans_details.comp_id = '$company'
            and trans_date BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' as date) and CAST('$enddate' as date)";
            $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
            if($stmt2 ===FALSE){
                die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
            }else{
              echo "<center><h3>CANTEEN TRANSACTION LISTING<br>Summary By Company</h3>
                <strong>Date From : </strong>".$datestart."&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>To : </strong>".$dateend."<br>";
            ?>
            <center><table border="1" cellpadding="4px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Cashier#</th>
                        <th>Total Txn</th>
                        <th>Total Amount (RM)</th>
                        <th>Total Cash (RM)</th>
                        <th>Total Subsidy (RM)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            <?php
            //count transaction
            $compname2 = "SELECT * from company where comp_id='$company'";
            $compp = sqlsrv_query($conn, $compname2);
              while ($c =sqlsrv_fetch_array($compp, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
              {
               echo "<center><strong> Company :</strong>".$c['comp_name']."</center><br><br>";
              }
             $txnT = 0;
             $sumAmount = 0;
             $sumCash = 0;
             $sumSubsidy = 0;
             $txn = "SELECT user_id,count(1) as txnT,sum(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(12,2))) as sumAmount,
             sum(CAST(cash AS DECIMAL(12,2))) as sumCash,sum(CAST(subsidy AS DECIMAL(12,2))) as sumSubsidy 
             from trans_details where trans_date BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' as date) and CAST('$enddate' as date) group by user_id";
             $res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $txn);
                        //count end

                    while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //fetching main query
                    {
                        while($num = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //fetching 1st condition
                        {
                            echo "<center><tr><td>".$num['user_id']."</td>"
                            . "<td align='right'>".$num['txnT']."</td>"
                            . "<td align='right'>".$num['sumAmount']."</td>"
                            . "<td align='right'>".$num['sumCash']."</td>"
                            . "<td align='right'>".$num['sumSubsidy']."</td>"
                            . "</tr>";       
                        }
                    }
                }
                    //sum up all 
                    $ttl = "SELECT count(1) as Txn,sum(CAST(amount as DECIMAL(12,2))) as ttlamount,
                    sum(CAST(cash AS DECIMAL(12,2))) as ttlcash,sum(CAST(subsidy AS DECIMAL(12,2))) as ttlsubsidy 
                    from trans_details where trans_date BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' as date) and CAST('$enddate' as date)";
                    $re = sqlsrv_query($conn, $ttl);
                                while($num_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($re, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //fetching 2nd condition
                                {
                                    echo "<tr>
                                    <td><strong>SUB TOTALS</strong></td>"
                                    ."<td align='right'><strong>".$num_row['Txn']."</strong></td>"
                                    ."<td align='right'><strong>".$num_row['ttlamount']."</strong></td>"
                                    ."<td align='right'><strong>".$num_row['ttlcash']."</strong></td>"
                                    ."<td align='right'><strong>".$num_row['ttlsubsidy']."</strong></td>"

                                    ."</tr></tbody></center>";
                                }
```

when I select 1-8-2017 until 21-8-2017 it shows this error

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampps\htdocs\CMSV2\report_type.php on line 134
>
> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampps\htdocs\CMSV2\report_type.php on line 148

which is

line 134 : `while($num = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))`

line 148 : `while($num_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($re, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))`

Can anyone explain why and how to solve it. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

**Make sure your table in database don't have empty cell :')**

Comment: warning says that first parameter to `sqlsrv_fetch_array` is boolean, so probably `$re` and `$res` are boolean false because query failed. Try to check it like you do with `$stmt2`

Comment: @Mr_KoKa I solved it, Actually I make silly mistake there is empty cell in my `trans_details` table.. Thanks for your concern :)